GitHub connection to Azure ML workspace
Is the only way available to make changes to m notebook in Azure ML workspace through the interface itself? Is it possible for me to make a CI/CD pipeline that takes the changes from a Git repository and deploys the changes to the Azure ML workspace?
I've read the Microsoft document but the only suggestion that they seem to give is to edit the notebook directly in the workspace.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks?view=azureml-api-2


Is the only way available to make changes to notebook in Azure ML workspace through the interface itself?

You can refer the steps in this document Git integration for Azure Machine Learning to clone repositories directly onto your workspace.
After you follow the steps in the document, the repository will be cloned onto your workspace. If you have made changes to your repo, you can use git pull commands to update it in your Azure Machine Learning workspace.
